# GREP for multiple strings with wildcard

Tags: grep

I am trying to copy lines from a log file from certain days.

Here's an example of what they look like.

```
2014-05-01T15:53:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): 

2014-04-301T11:08:10+00:00 DEBUG (7):
```

This GREP command works but only for exact strings:

> `grep -w '2014-04-30\|2014-04-29\|2014-04-28\|2014-04-27\|2014-04-26\|2014-04-25\|2014-04-24\|2014-04-23\|2014-04-22\|2014-04-21\|2014-04-202014-04-19' /test_custom.log > new_file.log`

When I try to add the wildcard, it doesn't. I also tried several other ways with same result.

> `grep -w '2014-04-30*\|2014-04-29*\|2014-04-28*\|2014-04-27*\|2014-04-26*\|2014-04-25*\|2014-04-24*\|2014-04-23*\|2014-04-22*\|2014-04-21*\|2014-04-20*' /test_custom.log > new_file.log`

Any suggestions?

Comment: * is not a wildcard in regex.

Comment: I'd try this question over on the SuperUser stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The asterisk `*` is not a wildcard in `grep`'s regex. It won't expand into a list of things varying from the last character. `*` stands for [Kleene closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), and is meant to accept/match 0 or more occurrences of the previous character/character class.

In your case, you should add a `.`, which stands for *accepts/matches any character*. The final expression should look like:

```
grep -w '2014-04-30.*\|2014-04-29.*\|2014-04-28.*\|2014-04-27.*\|
    2014-04-26.*\|2014-04-25.*\|2014-04-24.*\|2014-04-23.*\|2014-04-22.*\|
    2014-04-21.*\|2014-04-20.*' /test_custom.log > new_file.log
```

Which, although returns the result you want, is quite tiresome to write. Therefore, you should exploit `grep`'s regex capabilities, and try something a bit more concise, as in:

```
grep -w '2014-04-30.*\|2014-04-2[0-9]-.*' /test_custom.log > new_file.log
```